# Add custom icon on quill editor for displaying dropdown menu using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5, quill

Add a icon button here as shown, when clicked it would show dropdown using https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/

When clicked this icon
It should popdown options as shown below

[image: editor image]
[image]

When the Action menu is clicked it should write {{Action}} on the quill editor at cursor

When the Action action menu is clicked it should write {{Action action}} on the quill editor at cursor

When the Something else here menu is clicked it should write {{Something else here}} on the quill editor at cursor

```js
var toolbarOptions = ['bold', 'italic', 'image',
                {
                    size: ['small', false, 'large', 'huge']
                }, 'clean'
            ]
  
  var editor = new Quill('#editor', {
    modules: { toolbar: toolbarOptions },
    theme: 'snow',
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```